# Параллельная работа с базой данных: "The underlying provider failed on Open"

Tags: c#, база-данных

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, вот код:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(categories, category =>
                                                     {
                 var items = _productRepository.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryID == null || p.CategoryID == category.ID);

                 productArr.AddRange(items);
                                                     });
```

В этом коде у меня при параллельном обращении к базе данных через `Entity Framework 4` возникает исключение следующего типа:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

Как решить проблему? Каким образом возможно забрать в многопоточном цикле данные из базы?

Вот свойство репозитория, используемое мной

```
 public IQueryable<Product> Products
        {
            get
            {
                   return DbContext.Products;
            }
        }
```

Comment: хм. у вас же race condition по обращению к `productArr` на запись. попробуйте

    productArr.AddRange(
        categories.AsParallel().Select(category =>
            _productRepository.Products.Where(p =>
                p.CategoryID == null ||
                p.CategoryID == category.ID)));

хотя это, конечно, не решает основную проблему.

Comment: Первая же [ссылка][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open] из гугла